# Is there a way to fit a negative exponential (e.g. y = 1-exp(-x)) in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The exponential fit in Excel isn't really doing what I want it to do (the fitted exponential is clearly upside-down in the first graph) and I was wondering if there was an easy way to fix this or an explanation as to why it won't fit it the way I would like it to.

I had a quick fix which involved transforming the data (the second graph).

[image: Graphs and data]

Comment: "negative exponential" is called `log`:)

Comment: @MátéJuhász ln(x) is the inverse of e^x. What I am talking about is something like -e^(-x)

Comment: You can use Excel `solver` to fit, say, `y=a-b*exp(c*x)` to the data.

Comment: The log fits perfectly your data

Comment: @fernando.reyes that's not the method of fit that I want though, seeing as it is a first order system, I know that it should be an exponential not a logarithm.

Comment: @g.kov Do you just mean minimize the sum of the squares by changing a, b, and c? Or is there a built in function for fitting models with solver?

Comment: @Curtis:yes, just minimize the sum of the squares by changing a, b, and c.
With your data I've got `y=1.018-1.361*exp(0.446x)`,
`sumxmy2=0.0036`, `rsq=0.994`.
`

Comment: @g.kov interestingly close to the result that I got using the modded data, I had not thought of doing it the brute force method with solver though, good idea! Any idea why excel won't just fit it that way with the trend line function though?

Comment: @Curtis: as a guess, the standard `exe` trend function is probably just not flexible enough.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand well, but what you are asking seems wrong. Since `exp(x) > 0` for all `x`, you can't fit your data to an exponencial, because your Data is > 0, so you will never have something like `-exp(x)`.

Comment: Also, you want to do something like `exp(-x)`. If your argument `x` is negative, then your plot is wrong, because all values in your abscissa axis are positive. You can multiply all your abscissa values by `-1`, so Excel Fitted Data works properly.

Comment: @Thales what I meant was something like 1-exp(-x). Thank you for bringing this up